# SECCOMP_MODE_STRICT in unprivileged Docker container

Tags: docker, seccomp

When running a normal, unprivileged Docker container, it seems that SECCOMP_MODE_STRICT cannot be applied, returning `EINVAL`. `SECCOMP_MODE_FILTER` works correctly, and using `--privileged` or `--security-opt 'seccomp=unconfined'` allows `MODE_STRICT` to work. This question was asked before ([Is it possible to use SECCOMP_SET_MODE_STRICT inside an unprivileged docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62758867/is-it-possible-to-use-seccomp-set-mode-strict-inside-an-unprivileged-docker-cont)) but no real answer was given.

I see one workaround of instead using a BPF filter to perform the same function, but I would prefer to use a flag/capability to allow this instead.